# onReceive getting called multiple times

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I read this post: [Broadcast receiver onReceive() getting called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479101/broadcast-receiver-onreceive-getting-called-multiple-times)

But I didn't find the needed answer.

I've created a small utility function that overrides the onReceive() of BroadcastReceiver and rejects an incoming call based on certain conditions (which works fine).

Now once all the conditions are matched and I reject the call, I would like to store that number in the database (which again is an easy task). I would like to save the number in the database once I reject the call. But in the logs I observe that once there is an incoming call, the onReceive function gets called multiple times. If this is the case, I do not want multiple entries in my DB.

Is there any way by which the onReceive() would be called only once ? Or any workaround ?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your receiver will get called for three different state.on ringing, on hook and on idle state.

Check the phone state in onReceive.You may want to cut the call and store in db if its    state is ringing.

```
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
   Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    if (null == bundle) {
        return;
    }

    String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

    if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equalsIgnoreCase(state)) {
    //cut the call and store in db
    return;
    }


    } 
    if(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equalsIgnoreCase(state)) {
    return;
    }
     if(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK.equalsIgnoreCase(state)){
     return;
     }

   }
```

Comment: ya.. you are right.. but its not getting called 3 times. It is only getting called twice.

1. Once when the call is received
2. After cancelling the call

Thanks I'll check the condition accordingly now. Also any thoughts about the above code running successfully on other phones and various OS ?

Comment: @Rasel bundle is gonna be null on me. What is cauze?